# Get string inside given two characters using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Is there any way to push each value inside the brackets `< >`  to array using JavaScript?

As an example:

```
<And><Or><And><Eq><FieldRef Name="Editor" /><Value Type="User">XXX</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name="Document_x0020_Type" /><Value Type="Text">Audit</Value></Eq></And><Eq><FieldRef Name="Base_x0020_Content" /><Value Type="Text">Document</Value>
```

Output should be:

```
Array = ["And", "or", "And", "Eq", "FieldRef Name="Editor" /",.........]
```

Comment: *"Is there any way to ..."* - Yes, there is. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is, use regex **[`/<([^>]+)>/g`](https://regex101.com/r/yG5zX1/1)** and get captured group value. Use **[`RegExp.prototype.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)** method to get the captured value using regex.

```js
var str = '<And><Or><And><Eq><FieldRef Name="Editor" /><Value Type="User">XXX</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name="Document_x0020_Type" /><Value Type="Text">Audit</Value></Eq></And><Eq><FieldRef Name="Base_x0020_Content" /><Value Type="Text">Document</Value>';

var res = [],
  m,
  reg = /<([^>]+)>/g;

while (m = reg.exec(str))
  res.push(m[1])

console.log(res);
```

---

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/yG5zX1/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

Surely... lets do

```js
var str = '<And><Or><And><Eq><FieldRef Name="Editor" /><Value Type="User">XXX</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name="Document_x0020_Type" /><Value Type="Text">Audit</Value></Eq></And><Eq><FieldRef Name="Base_x0020_Content" /><Value Type="Text">Document</Value>',
    reg = /[^><]+/g,
    arr = str.match(reg);
console.log(arr);
```